# QTableWidget removeRow not actually deleting

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I have a QTableWidget filled with different QWidgets such that whenever I get a message from the server to add/update them I do so like this:

```
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(data.count());
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(data.count() - 1, 0, new QCheckBox("Enabled"));
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(data.count() - 1, 1, new QLineEdit("ADD"    ));
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(data.count() - 1, 2, new QComboBox(         ));
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(data.count() - 1, 3, new QLineEdit("232434" ));
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(data.count() - 1, 4, new QComboBox(         ));
```

Then with those widgets I signal/slot connect them in the next method like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TW_CNT; i++)
{
  connect(((QComboBox*)ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(cnt, i)), SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(cboxchanged(int)));
  if( i == 0)
  {
    //stuff
    connect((QCheckBox*)ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(cnt, i), SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(checkchanged(int)));
  }
  if( i == 1)
  {
    //stuff
    connect(((QComboBox*)ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(cnt, i)), SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(cboxchanged(int)));
    connect(((QComboBox*)ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(cnt, i)), SIGNAL(currentTextChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(cboxedited(QString)));
  }
  //....
}
```

Later when I want to remove stuff from tableWidget, I do so by calling removeRow on the row I no longer need. The issue here is that these widgets still seem to stay children of the ui->tableWidget->viewport() and they never get deleted even if I call ->deleteLater() on them. Deleting them with delete just causes my program to crash, and adding more rows after each row removal is causing my memory usage to skyrocket.

I've been stuck on this for a few days, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Whenever im using tables or lists etc in Qt and need to permanently remove a row i use `qDeleteAll(ui->table->selectedItems());` never had any issues with it, let me know if this works

Comment: @AngryDuck so, that doesn't actually crash, but it doesn't remove the children either, when I do:
`ui->tableWidget->selectRow(i);
qDeleteAll(ui->tableWidget->selectedItems());
ui->tableWidget->removeRow(i);`

nothing is actually deleted, and I think this is because I'm using QWidgets in the QTableWidget instead of QTableWidgeItems...

Everything I've read says QT is supposed to handle the delete for you when using removeRow, but I think it's not doing it because I'm using widgets and not items (which the QTableWidget is able to handle).